# How do I make a popup date picker for jQuery?

Tags: jquery

How do I make a popup date picker for jQuery?

Comment: This *has* to be a duplicate...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since four others have already posted the link as well, you can find an example here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Even better: http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/default.html

Answer (score 3):

You can use the jQuery UI datepicker. See http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Something like this perhaps? http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/

Answer (score 1):

Jquery UI has a datepicker control already.  Here is the [link](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com/) and use the [Datepicker Widget](http://jqueryui.com/demos/datepicker/)